# Qual a diferença entre paths iniciando com "./" e "~/" ? Qual representa uma melhor prática?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, path, webstorm

Ambos os diretórios abaixo apontam para o mesmo arquivo. 
Tratam-se de declarações de import do Typescript em uma aplicação Angular

`'~/app/shared/sevices/modules-services/inspections/checklist.service';`

`'./../../../shared/sevices/modules-services/inspections/checklist.service';`

Então qual a diferença entre usar o `./` e o `~/` ? Qual representa uma melhor prática ?

Comment: No sistema de arquivo o `~` aponta para `home`. Num web server o `~` aponta para a raiz do website.

Comment: O primeiro é um caminho absoluto, o segundo é relativo ao diretório atual. Então nem sempre eles apontarão para o mesmo arquivo. Mas falta contexto, isso aí está em declarações de `import` do TypeScript? Se não for isso, qual o contexto? De qualquer forma, o "melhor" depende de cada caso...

Comment: Exato, declarações de import do Typescript em uma aplicação Angular.

Comment: Então por favor clique em [edit] e adicione essas informações na pergunta. Coloque também as tags relacionadas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bom, tem duas maneiras, sendo elas:

> Terminal

Quando se fala de diretórios do sistema, quando se usa o `./`, ele aponta pro diretório atual, e quando se usa o `~/`, ele aponta pro diretório `home/username`.

> Programação

Mas, quando falamos de programação, por exemplo em react, você consegue definir caminhos relativos (e.g: react-app-rewired)

Então quando você dá um `import` em um arquivo usando `../../../../shared/etc`, você precisa ter cuidado toda vez, assim, diminuindo a produtividade.

Então você define caminhos relativos usando um caractere especial de sua escolha (os mais comuns são `~` e `@`)

Sendo assim, você aponta pro mesmo local usando `~/shared/etc` ou `~/app/shared/etc` (fica à escolha de sua configuração)

---

É uma boa prática utilizar caminhos relativos com `~/`, pois torna o desenvolvimento mais fácil e produtivo.

Comment: Lucas, o sinal `~/` funciona em Windows ? Tentei aqui e ele não funcionou.

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 sim, você consegue utilizar `cd ~/` usando o `Windows Powershell` ou `Windows Subsystem for Linux`.

Comment: Responder que funciona no Subsystem for Linux é pedantismo. O cara perguntou "Funciona no window?" a resposta é não, em Windows o `~` é apena um caractere que pode ser utilizado como nome de pasta

Comment: @JeanExtreme002, nem em powershell funciona: https://imgur.com/a/YdOdeWm

Comment: Okay, obrigado!

Comment: @AugustoVasques na primeira tentativa funcionou, mas você já estava na pasta `~/` :)
As outras tentativas foram totalmente erradas, já que `~~/` e `~/~/` não foram citadas aqui nesse post.

Comment: Você tem razão, `Set-Location ~/` vai para raiz do usuário. @JeanExtreme002 eu estou errado e o Lucas está correto, funciona no powershell.

Answer (score -1):

~/ são os diretórios e arquivos que estão na sua home e ./ se referem aos diretórios e arquivos do seu path atual, ~ é a mesma coisa que /home/user/

Comment: Notei que o VSCode normalmente faz a importação utilizando './' e que o WebStorm dá preferência ao '~/'Na geração de código (deploy) há alguma diferença?

Comment: Com o ~/ o caminho do arquivo é absoluto, é relativo ao home do usuário, com o ./ o caminho é relativo ao diretório que está sendo executado, o que pode mudar.